# Is "think" the lexical verb in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, syntactic-analysis, sentence

"People think that social interactions are vital for them."
Is "think" the lexical verb in this sentence? If so, can it be a transitive verb of incomplete predication? Because I consider that "social interactions" might be the direct object, and "are vital" the objective complement, but I am not sure.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If this is a class exercise, it's a bad one. This is a complex sentence, with two clauses, each of which has a lexical predicate: _think_ and _vital_. One is a lexical verb and the other is a lexical adjective. If the sentence were _People are aware that social interactions are vital for them_, there would be **no** lexical verb in the sentence.

Comment: "Think" is certainly a lexical verb, but it's not transitive. The content clause "that social interactions are vital for them" is not object of "think" but **complement**. The point that JL is making is that "be" is always an auxiliary verb, so in his example there is no lexical verb, only the auxiliary "be".